# Understanding GCC's un-optimized assembly for UB n = ++n + ++n - why increment twice before shifting?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, undefined-behavior

I understand this is undefined behaviour and no one actually writes code like this. However I'm curious as to what the compiler would do to this piece of code.

```
int n = 3;
n = ++n + ++n;
```

I compiled using both clang and gcc for comparison. **Without optimizations**. Here's the assembly generated from clang :

```
# clang -O0
movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %ecx
addl    $1, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -4(%rbp)
movl    -4(%rbp), %edx
addl    $1, %edx
movl    %edx, -4(%rbp)
addl    %edx, %ecx
movl    %ecx, -4(%rbp)
```

It's copying the `3` in a register, increments it, then copy this incremented value again and increment it once more, then add up `(3+1) + (3+1+1)`. This seems pretty straightforward.

However I'm having trouble understanding what GCC is doing. Here's the generated assembly :

```
# gcc -O0
movl    $3, -4(%rbp)
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
sall    -4(%rbp)
```

From what I understand, it's incrementing twice, and then left shift (`sall`) once, which means multiply by 2.

I thought it noticed `++n` being the same on both sides of the operand so it took it as common factor. However in that case why did it increment ***twice*** ?

Clang's version gives `9` and GCC gives `10`.  (Any result is acceptable, given the UB, but that confirms that the end result of the compilers' internal logic was actually different.)

Can anyone explain what is GCC trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: "I understand this is undefined behaviour" -- then just walk away. There's no point in trying to understand why undefined behavior behaves the way it does.

Comment: No I understand this is undefined behavior, I'm trying to understand what GCC is trying to accomplish by looking at the assembly.

Comment: There is a term in digital electronics called "don't care" - it is a combination of inputs, that should never happen. It is very useful, because in that case the logic can do *anything* in order to be optimized for the legal inputs. Same is here, this code is "don't care" and the compiler is doing something that in case of the code were legal would produce more optimized output.

Comment: I think since the order of operations is not defined here, GCC evaluates `++` two times and then adds up resulted value optimizing `n + n = 2n`

Comment: No one can understand because, no one can know what this line does as it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @geobreze, this is not about order of operations. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @prl I was trying to say that this is UB because of undefined order of operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unary `++` operator indicates that its operand is to be incremented before it is evaluated.  Clang interprets your expression like this:

```
n = n + 1
tmp1 = n
n = n + 1
tmp2 = n
n = tmp1 + tmp2
```

whereas GCC does something like this, processing the preincrements before descending into the expression:

```
n = n + 1
n = n + 1
tmp1 = n
tmp2 = n
n = tmp1 + tmp2
```

Then, realising that both operands to `+` are the same expression it performs a strength reduction yielding

```
n = n + 1
n = n + 1
n = n << 1
```

This strength reduction is likely performed despite the lack of optimisation flags because GCC is known to perform certain strength reductions very early in the compilation process before optimisation flags affect the result.

Note however that the result may differ with different compiler options.

Comment: Okay I'm accepting this because it actually answers my question. Yes I'm aware it can change and I was only asking about this particular case. Thanks .

Comment: I wouldn't say "before optimization flags affect the results".  e.g. at `-O0`, it still optimizes `n / 10` to use a multiplicative inverse.  But `-Os` will make it use `idiv`.  It's more like `-O0` doesn't mean *no* optimization; that's impossible with the way GCC is designed to transform the program through multiple internal representations.  `-O0` really means "compile fast, consistent debugging" not "no optimization".  It will still do some local stuff within single expressions or statements. See Basile's answer: [Disable all optimization options in GCC](//stackoverflow.com/q/33278757)

Comment: @PeterCordes Turning division into multiplication is not one of these early strength reductions.  AFAIK they are done in the parser and this is one of the major problems with using gcc for static analysis; you just don't have any way to get an AST that truly corresponds to the source code.